# Calculate Monthly Average price and plot using Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python

I have a Dataframe which contains sold house prices in two areas over a daily period from Oct 2021 till today.

I want to find the average house price per month and plot a graph using plotly to see if prices are going down or up in each area.

**Sample DataFrame:**

```
DateSold            Price    Area
12/10/2021 00:00    300000  Area A
17/10/2021 00:00    350000  Area B
18/10/2021 00:00    400000  Area B
11/12/2021 00:00    412000  Area A
17/12/2021 00:00    315000  Area A
08/01/2022 00:00    385000  Area A
09/01/2022 00:00    445000  Area A
15/01/2022 00:00    309000  Area B
15/01/2022 00:00    350000  Area B
```

I tried to convert the datetime column into a PeriodIndex on monthly frequency, then take the mean using GroupBy.mean:

```
df2.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df2['Datesold'], freq="M"))['Price'].mean()
```

Can someone point me in the right direction in how I can achieve the average house price per month and plot that using plotly?

I was using the below code for plotly

```
fig = px.line(df, x = df['DateSold'], y = df['Price'], title='Average sold house price
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DateTime column does not have a frequency or periodicity. Even if it were the case, you wouldn't need to convert to `PeriodIndex`. You can group by using the month/month_name of the `DateSold` column as follows:

```py
# convert object to datetime
df.DateSold = pd.to_datetime(df.DateSold, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

# compute the monthly averages
df_avg = df.groupby(df.DateSold.dt.month_name(), as_index=True)['Price'].mean()
```

```
DateSold
December    363500.0
January     372250.0
October     350000.0
```

You can then plot the result with plotly

```py
fig = px.bar(df_avg, x = df_avg.index, y = df_avg, title='Average sold house price')
fig
```

Comment: Hi @Kaymal - I don't understand what you mean my DateSold column doesnt have a frequency? It is a daily frequency no?
Also, with your code I get the below error "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

Comment: I'm guessing thats because my 'DateSold' is not in pd.to_datetime?

Comment: I mean ıt doesn't have a fixed frequency as described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects). If it were daily, it should have had data for every day between the start and end dates. For the error, I've updated answer to add the code that converts the `DateSold` column to `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks.. So this is working as i need but the dates are not in order in the graph. E.g. my graph starts April then goes to October then comes back to March. What is the best way to order the data by months?

Comment: Additionally, is there a way I can keep the month and year instead of just the month with the dt accessor?